# Variable outside foreach loop

Tags: php, foreach

here is my PHP code:

```
if( !empty($row_edit) ){
            $stageDates = explode(', ',$row_edit['placement_stage_date']);
            foreach( $stageDates as $stageDate ){
                  echo $stageDate.'<br/>';
            }
   }
```

Now, I want to print the value of $stageDate in each below input-boxes like,

```
<input type="text" name="placement_stage_date[]" value="<?php echo $stageDate; ?>" />
```

I'm having 5 input-boxes but what I'm getting here is only the last value in each textboxes.

Comment: You only ask for the last item in your case. Did you mean to put that HTML output inside your loop? Because that would do what you want.

Comment: and yes, I want to print that variable in the input-boxes which is outside the foreach loop

Comment: Where is your question?

Comment: @inetphantom I'm having 5 input-boxes but what I'm getting here is only the last value in each textboxes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$date_array = array();
if( !empty($row_edit) ){
    $stageDates = explode(', ',$row_edit['placement_stage_date']);
    foreach( $stageDates as $stageDate ){
        //echo $stageDate.'<br/>';
        $date_array[] = $stageDate;
    }
}
// print $stageDate value outside of loop, something like this

<input type="text" name="placement_stage_date[]" value="<?php echo $date_array[0]; ?>" />
<input type="text" name="placement_stage_date[]" value="<?php echo $date_array[1]; ?>" />
<input type="text" name="placement_stage_date[]" value="<?php echo $date_array[2]; ?>" />
```

Comment: hey, it works. But is there any method like using a "keep changing" variable instead of providing the manual values like 0,1,2 ?

Comment: You write an array with a foreachloop to an array, so just use ``$stageDates[i]`` would be better or?

Comment: @Rocky but where is the i comes from ? don't need to declare "i" ?

Comment: @vitally look at my answer (:

Answer (score 1):

You want something like this?

```
$data = [];
if( !empty($row_edit) ){
    $stageDates = explode(', ',$row_edit['placement_stage_date']);
    foreach( $stageDates as $key => $stageDate ) {
        $data[$key] = $stageDate;
    }
}
foreach($data as $key => $row) {
    echo "<input type='text' name='stageDate".$key."' value='".$row."' />";
}
```

Comment: I want that input element outside the loop brother.

Comment: @vitally how about now?

Comment: You write an array with a foreachloop to an array, so just use ``$stageDates[i]`` would be better or?

Comment: The author of the post wants the input element outside of the first loop for some reason.

Comment: @Lexx btw you use a php tag inside a echo

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```html
if( !empty($row_edit) ){
            $stageDates = explode(', ',$row_edit['placement_stage_date']);
            foreach( $stageDates as $stageDate ){
                  ?>
                  <input type="text" name="placement_stage_date[]" value="<?php echo $stageDate; ?>" />
                  <?php
            }
   }
```

Comment: no no bro. I want that input element outside the loop

Comment: Where outside the box can you give some example

Answer (score 0):

You can create a helper class then you have separed the code.

```
require('HelperHtml.php')
if( !empty($row_edit ) {
    $stageDates = explode(', ',$row_edit['placement_stage_date']);
    HelperHtml::createInputText('placement_stage_date[]', $stageDates)
}
```

Now HelperHtml.php

```
class HelperHtml
{
    public static function createInputText ($name, array $values)
    {
        foreach($values as $value) {
            echo "<input type='text' name='".$name."' value='".$value."' />";
        }
    }
}
```